# Access VBA: write on selected record

Tags: ms-access, vba

The form shows one record per time. I would like that, by clicking a button, the system puts a value on the table of the DB, in the row of the selected record. Something like:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand write "example" in the field <FieldName> of the selected record
```

Is it possible something like that?

Comment: You mean, on a form? That shouldn't be hard, just `Me.MyField.Value = "SomeValue"`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth sorry it wasn't clear. I have edited the question. I would like that the word "example" could be written into the **table**. The form does not have any `Controls` for that field, so I cannot use `Me.MyField.Value`.

Comment: Build an sql update statement with the required criteria for the row e.g. 'update myTable set theFieldIWantToUpdate = someThingShownOnMyForm where myCriteriaField = someOtherThingShownOnMyForm' then run it with CurrentDB.Execute theStringIJustBuilt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is bind the field to a textbox, then set property *Visible* of the textbox to False.

Now, call this code in your *OnClick* event:

```
Me!NameOfTextbox.Value = "example"
' Save the record.
Me.Dirty = False
```